# How to estimate multivariate Bernoulli with missing labels

Tags: neural-networks, maximum-likelihood, missing-data, bernoulli-distribution

I want to estimate a multivariate Bernoulli distribution with missing labels, without assuming independence. The dataset is from https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/shape/attributes-poselets-iccv11.pdf, and consists of images and eight binary attribute labels such as "has long hair." I am interested in estimating the joint distribution of these labels, which I denote as $y \in \{0, 1\}^8$. The labels were obtained from five Amazon mechanical turk workers, and a label is considered missing if there is less than a 3/5 worker consensus on the label.

I am asking about how to estimate $p(y)$. I have already successfully estimated $p(y \mid x)$ by parameterizing it with a neural network, and marginalizing over the missing labels to maximize the observed data log-likelihood.

However, I'm not sure what to do when there is no $x$, and we are just estimating $p(y)$. In this case, there is no input to feed into the forward pass of the neural network.

Comment: I don't understand the question, I am sorry. Can you maybe tell us what data you have and how you think it could be distributed, i.e. how you want to model it?

Comment: The data is in $\{0, 1\}^d$ where $d = 8$ in my case, and I want to model it with a multivariate Bernoulli distribution. The complication is that entries of this vector are often missing, e.g. an example would be $[0, 1, nan, nan, 0, 1, nan, 0]$

Comment: Obtaining a valid answer requires knowing *why* some values are missing.  Please include that information in your question.

Comment: An approach that can in principle work with binary and missing data (assuming missing at random) and with binary data would be categorical PCA using expectation maximisation. One starting point for that is chapter 12.4 of Kevin Murphy's Machine Learning: a probabilistic approach. It is freely available here: https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book1.html.

Still, the problem you are tackling sounds more like a label noise problem and I have no idea if that will work well.

Comment: Thank you. My current baseline is to estimate the marginals, and assume that the joint factorizes. I think this may be a pretty poor baseline, since there are clear dependencies between the labels, e.g. some are mutually exclusive, such as "wearing long pants" and "wearing shorts."